# Redirect non-www to www., AND rewrite everything to /

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite

I want to redirect all traffic to example.com to www.example.com, and then rewrite everything to /.

So if a visitor by some reason hits http://example.com/foo/bar I want to redirect them to http://www.example.com/foo/bar and then rewrite that request to /index.php

This is what I've got so far (the non-www to www redirect works):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^11\.22\.33\.44
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

EDIT:

Okay I've got it to work with this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^123\.123\.123\.123
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

BUT the strangest thing: Apache does something weird with http://www.example.com/home -- it's just like apache has some internal routing for this path because it bypasses my vhost conf and sends its own 404. And there isn't any `/home` in my document root so the -s/-d/-l shouldn't matter. Also I've grep:ed for home in `/etc/apache2` without any hits.

Anyone?

**Update:**

I'm seeing this in the apache error log: `[Fri Mar 25 04:33:45 2011] [error] [client 123.123.123.123] File does not exist: /var/www/example/web/home`

So I guess that the request hits my vhost but isn't caught by my rules?

**Update 2:**

This is weird. If I removed this line `RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]` the request to `/home` came trough. But only requests to `/home`.

Instead I ended up with following config, which works:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^123\.123\.123\.123
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]

<Location />
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|txt)$ /index.php
</Location>
```

Comment: You can easilect www to non www version and from non www version. Check the method at http://tipsntrix.in/www-non-www-htaccess-redirect/

Answer (score 0):

add

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Where should I add that? Is it supposed to replace something? Thanks.